# Can't pass data from separate model in the instance variable in React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a React-Rails app that displays a table of Sites, each Site belonging to a Trust.

In my SitesController, in the index action, @sites = Site.includes(:trust).

When I go to my sites view page (views/sites/index.html.erb), I can access the attributes of the Trust data. For example, the code below works fine:

```
<% @sites.each do |s| %>
<p> <%= s.trust.name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

However, when I pass the @sites instance variable to my React app, it says that trust is undefined.

Here's the code from the view page:

```
<%= react_component 'Sites', {sites: @sites} %>
```

Here's the relevant code from the React component:

```
render () {
  const sites = this.props.sites.map((site) => {
    return (
        <p>{site.trust.name}</p> // returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
      );
  });
  return (
      <div>
        {sites}
      </div>
  );
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which react gem you use? Do you read the documentation for this gem?

Comment: I'm using react-rails, but I couldn't seem to find the answer in the documentation.